# Flutter Table Calendar : Showing Event from API to Table Calendar

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show Calendar and including event, the event already exists from API. I searching plugin fit to my case and I found [Table Calendar Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar). I read the example to show the event Manually and found it :

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final _selectedDay = DateTime.now();

    _events = {
      _selectedDay.subtract(Duration(days: 30)): ['Event A0', 'Event B0', 'Event C0'],
      _selectedDay.subtract(Duration(days: 27)): ['Event A1'],
      _selectedDay.subtract(Duration(days: 20)): ['Event A2', 'Event B2', 'Event C2', 'Event D2'],
      _selectedDay.subtract(Duration(days: 16)): ['Event A3', 'Event B3'],
      _selectedDay.subtract(Duration(days: 10)): ['Event A4', 'Event B4', 'Event C4'],
      _selectedDay.subtract(Duration(days: 4)): ['Event A5', 'Event B5', 'Event C5'],
      _selectedDay.subtract(Duration(days: 2)): ['Event A6', 'Event B6'],
      _selectedDay: ['Event A7', 'Event B7', 'Event C7', 'Event D7'],
      _selectedDay.add(Duration(days: 1)): ['Event A8', 'Event B8', 'Event C8', 'Event D8'],
      _selectedDay.add(Duration(days: 3)): Set.from(['Event A9', 'Event A9', 'Event B9']).toList(),
      _selectedDay.add(Duration(days: 7)): ['Event A10', 'Event B10', 'Event C10'],
      _selectedDay.add(Duration(days: 11)): ['Event A11', 'Event B11'],
      _selectedDay.add(Duration(days: 17)): ['Event A12', 'Event B12', 'Event C12', 'Event D12'],
      _selectedDay.add(Duration(days: 22)): ['Event A13', 'Event B13'],
      _selectedDay.add(Duration(days: 26)): ['Event A14', 'Event B14', 'Event C14'],
    };

    _selectedEvents = _events[_selectedDay] ?? [];
    _calendarController = CalendarController();

    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    );

    _animationController.forward();
  }
```

But the above example to show event is static, I need to show event already exist from my API to [Table Calendar](https://github.com/aleksanderwozniak/table_calendar/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart) dynamically.

I'm so new for this package, How can I handle my case?

## Result API

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "message": "Event Is Found",
    "data": [
        {
            "kodeEvent": "1",
            "tanggalEvent": "2020-01-15",
            "judulEvent": "Bangun Kembali 200 Masjid dan Mushalla Anti Gempa",
            "lokasiEvent": "Lombok",
            "isiEvent": "Gempa Bumi dahsyat bertubi-tubi guncang lombok, kini Pulau seribu Masjid lemah tak berdaya, Lebih dari 500 Masjid dan Mushalla rata dengan tanah, kini ibadah saudara kita harus bertebaran dimana-mana , masih banyak warga yang tak bisa melaksanakan shalat dengan nyaman. Lokasi masjid dan mushalla sudah tak dapat dipake kembali , semua rusak parah dan bahkan sudh rata dengan tanah.<br /><br />Terpaksa mereka shalat di luar, tempat terbuka , bahkan di atas reruntuhan bangunan rumah sekalipun. Kini tak kurang dari 300 Masjid dan Mushalla yang dilaporkan rusak, dan lebih dari 70 masjid yang hancur rata dengan tanah karena gempa. semua masjid ini tersebar di 3 kabupaten (lombok utara, lombok barat dan lombok timur).",
            "fotoEvent": "event_5e4b8cd198530_202002181405.jpg",
            "waktuEvent": "09:00 s.d Selesai",
            "statusEvent": "t",
            "createBy": "0",
            "createTime": "2020-01-29 16:37:26",
            "updateBy": "",
            "updateTime": "2020-02-18 14:05:53"
        },
        {
            "kodeEvent": "2",
            "tanggalEvent": "2020-03-31",
            "judulEvent": "Bangun Kembali 100 Masjid dan Mushalla Anti Gempa",
            "lokasiEvent": "Jakarta",
            "isiEvent": "Gempa Bumi dahsyat bertubi-tubi guncang lombok, kini Pulau seribu Masjid lemah tak berdaya, Lebih dari 500 Masjid dan Mushalla rata dengan tanah, kini ibadah saudara kita harus bertebaran dimana-mana , masih banyak warga yang tak bisa melaksanakan shalat dengan nyaman. Lokasi masjid dan mushalla sudah tak dapat dipake kembali , semua rusak parah dan bahkan sudh rata dengan tanah.<br /><br />Terpaksa mereka shalat di luar, tempat terbuka , bahkan di atas reruntuhan bangunan rumah sekalipun. Kini tak kurang dari 300 Masjid dan Mushalla yang dilaporkan rusak, dan lebih dari 70 masjid yang hancur rata dengan tanah karena gempa. semua masjid ini tersebar di 3 kabupaten (lombok utara, lombok barat dan lombok timur).",
            "fotoEvent": "event_5e4b8d3d74b44_202002181407.jpg",
            "waktuEvent": "09:00 s.d Selesai",
            "statusEvent": "t",
            "createBy": "",
            "createTime": "2020-02-18 14:07:41",
            "updateBy": "",
            "updateTime": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "kodeEvent": "3",
            "tanggalEvent": "2020-01-31",
            "judulEvent": "Bangun Kembali 200 Masjid dan Mushalla Anti Gempa",
            "lokasiEvent": "Bandung",
            "isiEvent": "Gempa Bumi dahsyat bertubi-tubi guncang lombok, kini Pulau seribu Masjid lemah tak berdaya, Lebih dari 500 Masjid dan Mushalla rata dengan tanah, kini ibadah saudara kita harus bertebaran dimana-mana , masih banyak warga yang tak bisa melaksanakan shalat dengan nyaman. Lokasi masjid dan mushalla sudah tak dapat dipake kembali , semua rusak parah dan bahkan sudh rata dengan tanah.<br /><br />Terpaksa mereka shalat di luar, tempat terbuka , bahkan di atas reruntuhan bangunan rumah sekalipun. Kini tak kurang dari 300 Masjid dan Mushalla yang dilaporkan rusak, dan lebih dari 70 masjid yang hancur rata dengan tanah karena gempa. semua masjid ini tersebar di 3 kabupaten (lombok utara, lombok barat dan lombok timur).",
            "fotoEvent": "event_5e4b8d72e2d37_202002181408.jpg",
            "waktuEvent": "09:00 s.d Selesai",
            "statusEvent": "t",
            "createBy": "",
            "createTime": "2020-02-18 14:08:34",
            "updateBy": "",
            "updateTime": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

## Model

```
import 'dart:convert';

class EventModel {
  String kodeEvent;
  DateTime tanggalEvent;
  String judulEvent;
  String lokasiEvent;
  String isiEvent;
  String fotoEvent;
  String waktuEvent;
  String statusEvent;
  String createBy;
  DateTime createTime;
  String updateBy;
  String updateTime;

  EventModel({
    this.kodeEvent,
    this.tanggalEvent,
    this.judulEvent,
    this.lokasiEvent,
    this.isiEvent,
    this.fotoEvent,
    this.waktuEvent,
    this.statusEvent,
    this.createBy,
    this.createTime,
    this.updateBy,
    this.updateTime,
  });

  factory EventModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => EventModel(
        kodeEvent: json["kodeEvent"],
        tanggalEvent: DateTime.parse(json["tanggalEvent"]),
        judulEvent: json["judulEvent"],
        lokasiEvent: json["lokasiEvent"],
        isiEvent: json["isiEvent"],
        fotoEvent: json["fotoEvent"],
        waktuEvent: json["waktuEvent"],
        statusEvent: json["statusEvent"],
        createBy: json["createBy"],
        createTime: DateTime.parse(json["createTime"]),
        updateBy: json["updateBy"],
        updateTime: json["updateTime"],
      );
}
```

## Event Screen

```
class _EventScreenState extends State<EventScreen> {
  Future<List<EventModel>> getAllEvent;

  CalendarController calendarController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    calendarController = CalendarController();
    getAllEvent = eventApi.getAllEvent();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    calendarController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          TableCalendar(
            calendarController: calendarController,
            startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
            events: ,
          ),
          FutureBuilder(
            future: getAllEvent,
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<List<EventModel>> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return ErrorFutureBuilder(errorText: snapshot.error);
                } else {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      final result = snapshot.data[index];
                      return Text(result.tanggalEvent);
                    },
                  );
                }
              } else {
                return LoadingFutureBuilder();
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## GetAllEvent

```
 Future<List<EventModel>> getAllEvent() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(_baseUrl);
      final Map<String, dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseJson["status"] == "ok") {
        List eventList = responseJson['data'];
        final result = eventList
            .map<EventModel>((json) => EventModel.fromJson(json))
            .toList();
        return result;
      } else {
        throw CustomError(responseJson['message']);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return Future.error(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

## My Current Result

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
I simulate network delay with 3 seconds.

**code snippet for you model**

```
Future<Map<DateTime, List>> getTask1() async {
    Map<DateTime, List> mapFetch = {};
    List<EventModel> event = await getAllEvent();
    for (int i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {
      var createTime = DateTime(event[i].createTime.year,
          event[i].createTime.month, event[i].createTime.day);
      var original = mapFetch[createTime];
      if (original == null) {
        print("null");
        mapFetch[createTime] = [event[i].tanggalEvent];
      } else {
        print(event[i].tanggalEvent);
        mapFetch[createTime] = List.from(original)
          ..addAll([event[i].tanggalEvent]);
      }
    }

    return mapFetch;
  }
```

code snippet

```
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          getTask().then((val) => setState(() {
            _events = val;
          }));
          //print( ' ${_events.toString()} ');
        });


     Future<Map<DateTime, List>> getTask() async {
            Map<DateTime, List> mapFetch = {};

            await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {});

            String responseString = '''
{
    "status": "ok",
    "message": "Event Is Found",
  ...
                Event event = eventFromJson(responseString);

    for (int i = 0; i < event.data.length; i++) {
      var createTime = DateTime(event.data[i].createTime.year,
          event.data[i].createTime.month, event.data[i].createTime.day);
      var original = mapFetch[createTime];
      if (original == null) {
        print("null");
        mapFetch[createTime] = [event.data[i].tanggalEvent];
      } else {
        print(event.data[i].tanggalEvent);
        mapFetch[createTime] = List.from(original)..addAll([event.data[i].tanggalEvent]);
      }
    }

    return mapFetch;
    }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

Event eventFromJson(String str) => Event.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String eventToJson(Event data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Event {
  String status;
  String message;
  List<Datum> data;

  Event({
    this.status,
    this.message,
    this.data,
  });

  factory Event.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Event(
        status: json["status"],
        message: json["message"],
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "message": message,
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Datum {
  String kodeEvent;
  DateTime tanggalEvent;
  String judulEvent;
  String lokasiEvent;
  String isiEvent;
  String fotoEvent;
  String waktuEvent;
  String statusEvent;
  String createBy;
  DateTime createTime;
  String updateBy;
  String updateTime;

  Datum({
    this.kodeEvent,
    this.tanggalEvent,
    this.judulEvent,
    this.lokasiEvent,
    this.isiEvent,
    this.fotoEvent,
    this.waktuEvent,
    this.statusEvent,
    this.createBy,
    this.createTime,
    this.updateBy,
    this.updateTime,
  });

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        kodeEvent: json["kodeEvent"],
        tanggalEvent: DateTime.parse(json["tanggalEvent"]),
        judulEvent: json["judulEvent"],
        lokasiEvent: json["lokasiEvent"],
        isiEvent: json["isiEvent"],
        fotoEvent: json["fotoEvent"],
        waktuEvent: json["waktuEvent"],
        statusEvent: json["statusEvent"],
        createBy: json["createBy"],
        createTime: DateTime.parse(json["createTime"]),
        updateBy: json["updateBy"],
        updateTime: json["updateTime"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "kodeEvent": kodeEvent,
        "tanggalEvent":
            "${tanggalEvent.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${tanggalEvent.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${tanggalEvent.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "judulEvent": judulEvent,
        "lokasiEvent": lokasiEvent,
        "isiEvent": isiEvent,
        "fotoEvent": fotoEvent,
        "waktuEvent": waktuEvent,
        "statusEvent": statusEvent,
        "createBy": createBy,
        "createTime": createTime.toIso8601String(),
        "updateBy": updateBy,
        "updateTime": updateTime,
      };
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  List _selectedEvents;
  int _counter = 0;
  Map<DateTime, List> _events;
  CalendarController _calendarController;
  AnimationController _animationController;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  Future<List<EventModel>> getAllEvent() async {
    try {
      //final response = await http.get(_baseUrl);

      String responseString = '''
{
    "status": "ok",
    "message": "Event Is Found",
    "data": [
        {
            "kodeEvent": "1",
            "tanggalEvent": "2020-01-15",
            "judulEvent": "Bangun Kembali 200 Masjid dan Mushalla Anti Gempa",
            "lokasiEvent": "Lombok",
            "isiEvent": "Gempa Bumi dahsyat bertubi-tubi guncang lombok, kini Pulau seribu Masjid lemah tak berdaya, Lebih dari 500 Masjid dan Mushalla rata dengan tanah, kini ibadah saudara kita harus bertebaran dimana-mana , masih banyak warga yang tak bisa melaksanakan shalat dengan nyaman. Lokasi masjid dan mushalla sudah tak dapat dipake kembali , semua rusak parah dan bahkan sudh rata dengan tanah.<br /><br />Terpaksa mereka shalat di luar, tempat terbuka , bahkan di atas reruntuhan bangunan rumah sekalipun. Kini tak kurang dari 300 Masjid dan Mushalla yang dilaporkan rusak, dan lebih dari 70 masjid yang hancur rata dengan tanah karena gempa. semua masjid ini tersebar di 3 kabupaten (lombok utara, lombok barat dan lombok timur).",
            "fotoEvent": "event_5e4b8cd198530_202002181405.jpg",
            "waktuEvent": "09:00 s.d Selesai",
            "statusEvent": "t",
            "createBy": "0",
            "createTime": "2020-01-29 16:37:26",
            "updateBy": "",
            "updateTime": "2020-02-18 14:05:53"
        },
        {
            "kodeEvent": "2",
            "tanggalEvent": "2020-03-31",
            "judulEvent": "Bangun Kembali 100 Masjid dan Mushalla Anti Gempa",
            "lokasiEvent": "Jakarta",
            "isiEvent": "Gempa Bumi dahsyat bertubi-tubi guncang lombok, kini Pulau seribu Masjid lemah tak berdaya, Lebih dari 500 Masjid dan Mushalla rata dengan tanah, kini ibadah saudara kita harus bertebaran dimana-mana , masih banyak warga yang tak bisa melaksanakan shalat dengan nyaman. Lokasi masjid dan mushalla sudah tak dapat dipake kembali , semua rusak parah dan bahkan sudh rata dengan tanah.<br /><br />Terpaksa mereka shalat di luar, tempat terbuka , bahkan di atas reruntuhan bangunan rumah sekalipun. Kini tak kurang dari 300 Masjid dan Mushalla yang dilaporkan rusak, dan lebih dari 70 masjid yang hancur rata dengan tanah karena gempa. semua masjid ini tersebar di 3 kabupaten (lombok utara, lombok barat dan lombok timur).",
            "fotoEvent": "event_5e4b8d3d74b44_202002181407.jpg",
            "waktuEvent": "09:00 s.d Selesai",
            "statusEvent": "t",
            "createBy": "",
            "createTime": "2020-02-18 14:07:41",
            "updateBy": "",
            "updateTime": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "kodeEvent": "3",
            "tanggalEvent": "2020-01-31",
            "judulEvent": "Bangun Kembali 200 Masjid dan Mushalla Anti Gempa",
            "lokasiEvent": "Bandung",
            "isiEvent": "Gempa Bumi dahsyat bertubi-tubi guncang lombok, kini Pulau seribu Masjid lemah tak berdaya, Lebih dari 500 Masjid dan Mushalla rata dengan tanah, kini ibadah saudara kita harus bertebaran dimana-mana , masih banyak warga yang tak bisa melaksanakan shalat dengan nyaman. Lokasi masjid dan mushalla sudah tak dapat dipake kembali , semua rusak parah dan bahkan sudh rata dengan tanah.<br /><br />Terpaksa mereka shalat di luar, tempat terbuka , bahkan di atas reruntuhan bangunan rumah sekalipun. Kini tak kurang dari 300 Masjid dan Mushalla yang dilaporkan rusak, dan lebih dari 70 masjid yang hancur rata dengan tanah karena gempa. semua masjid ini tersebar di 3 kabupaten (lombok utara, lombok barat dan lombok timur).",
            "fotoEvent": "event_5e4b8d72e2d37_202002181408.jpg",
            "waktuEvent": "09:00 s.d Selesai",
            "statusEvent": "t",
            "createBy": "",
            "createTime": "2020-02-18 14:08:34",
            "updateBy": "",
            "updateTime": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        }      
    ]
}
    ''';

      final Map<String, dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(responseString);
      if (responseJson["status"] == "ok") {
        List eventList = responseJson['data'];
        final result = eventList
            .map<EventModel>((json) => EventModel.fromJson(json))
            .toList();
        return result;
      } else {
        //throw CustomError(responseJson['message']);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return Future.error(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<Map<DateTime, List>> getTask1() async {
    Map<DateTime, List> mapFetch = {};
    List<EventModel> event = await getAllEvent();
    for (int i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {
      var createTime = DateTime(event[i].createTime.year,
          event[i].createTime.month, event[i].createTime.day);
      var original = mapFetch[createTime];
      if (original == null) {
        print("null");
        mapFetch[createTime] = [event[i].tanggalEvent];
      } else {
        print(event[i].tanggalEvent);
        mapFetch[createTime] = List.from(original)
          ..addAll([event[i].tanggalEvent]);
      }
    }

    return mapFetch;
  }

  Future<Map<DateTime, List>> getTask() async {
    Map<DateTime, List> mapFetch = {};

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {});

    /*String link = baseURL + fetchTodoByDate;
    var res = await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(link), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      // need help in creating fetch logic here
    }*/

    String responseString = '''
{
    "status": "ok",
    "message": "Event Is Found",
    "data": [
        {
            "kodeEvent": "1",
            "tanggalEvent": "2020-01-15",
            "judulEvent": "Bangun Kembali 200 Masjid dan Mushalla Anti Gempa",
            "lokasiEvent": "Lombok",
            "isiEvent": "Gempa Bumi dahsyat bertubi-tubi guncang lombok, kini Pulau seribu Masjid lemah tak berdaya, Lebih dari 500 Masjid dan Mushalla rata dengan tanah, kini ibadah saudara kita harus bertebaran dimana-mana , masih banyak warga yang tak bisa melaksanakan shalat dengan nyaman. Lokasi masjid dan mushalla sudah tak dapat dipake kembali , semua rusak parah dan bahkan sudh rata dengan tanah.<br /><br />Terpaksa mereka shalat di luar, tempat terbuka , bahkan di atas reruntuhan bangunan rumah sekalipun. Kini tak kurang dari 300 Masjid dan Mushalla yang dilaporkan rusak, dan lebih dari 70 masjid yang hancur rata dengan tanah karena gempa. semua masjid ini tersebar di 3 kabupaten (lombok utara, lombok barat dan lombok timur).",
            "fotoEvent": "event_5e4b8cd198530_202002181405.jpg",
            "waktuEvent": "09:00 s.d Selesai",
            "statusEvent": "t",
            "createBy": "0",
            "createTime": "2020-01-29 16:37:26",
            "updateBy": "",
            "updateTime": "2020-02-18 14:05:53"
        },
        {
            "kodeEvent": "2",
            "tanggalEvent": "2020-03-31",
            "judulEvent": "Bangun Kembali 100 Masjid dan Mushalla Anti Gempa",
            "lokasiEvent": "Jakarta",
            "isiEvent": "Gempa Bumi dahsyat bertubi-tubi guncang lombok, kini Pulau seribu Masjid lemah tak berdaya, Lebih dari 500 Masjid dan Mushalla rata dengan tanah, kini ibadah saudara kita harus bertebaran dimana-mana , masih banyak warga yang tak bisa melaksanakan shalat dengan nyaman. Lokasi masjid dan mushalla sudah tak dapat dipake kembali , semua rusak parah dan bahkan sudh rata dengan tanah.<br /><br />Terpaksa mereka shalat di luar, tempat terbuka , bahkan di atas reruntuhan bangunan rumah sekalipun. Kini tak kurang dari 300 Masjid dan Mushalla yang dilaporkan rusak, dan lebih dari 70 masjid yang hancur rata dengan tanah karena gempa. semua masjid ini tersebar di 3 kabupaten (lombok utara, lombok barat dan lombok timur).",
            "fotoEvent": "event_5e4b8d3d74b44_202002181407.jpg",
            "waktuEvent": "09:00 s.d Selesai",
            "statusEvent": "t",
            "createBy": "",
            "createTime": "2020-02-18 14:07:41",
            "updateBy": "",
            "updateTime": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "kodeEvent": "3",
            "tanggalEvent": "2020-01-31",
            "judulEvent": "Bangun Kembali 200 Masjid dan Mushalla Anti Gempa",
            "lokasiEvent": "Bandung",
            "isiEvent": "Gempa Bumi dahsyat bertubi-tubi guncang lombok, kini Pulau seribu Masjid lemah tak berdaya, Lebih dari 500 Masjid dan Mushalla rata dengan tanah, kini ibadah saudara kita harus bertebaran dimana-mana , masih banyak warga yang tak bisa melaksanakan shalat dengan nyaman. Lokasi masjid dan mushalla sudah tak dapat dipake kembali , semua rusak parah dan bahkan sudh rata dengan tanah.<br /><br />Terpaksa mereka shalat di luar, tempat terbuka , bahkan di atas reruntuhan bangunan rumah sekalipun. Kini tak kurang dari 300 Masjid dan Mushalla yang dilaporkan rusak, dan lebih dari 70 masjid yang hancur rata dengan tanah karena gempa. semua masjid ini tersebar di 3 kabupaten (lombok utara, lombok barat dan lombok timur).",
            "fotoEvent": "event_5e4b8d72e2d37_202002181408.jpg",
            "waktuEvent": "09:00 s.d Selesai",
            "statusEvent": "t",
            "createBy": "",
            "createTime": "2020-02-18 14:08:34",
            "updateBy": "",
            "updateTime": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        }      
    ]
}
    ''';

    Event event = eventFromJson(responseString);

    for (int i = 0; i < event.data.length; i++) {
      var createTime = DateTime(event.data[i].createTime.year,
          event.data[i].createTime.month, event.data[i].createTime.day);
      var original = mapFetch[createTime];
      if (original == null) {
        print("null");
        mapFetch[createTime] = [event.data[i].tanggalEvent];
      } else {
        print(event.data[i].tanggalEvent);
        mapFetch[createTime] = List.from(original)
          ..addAll([event.data[i].tanggalEvent]);
      }
    }

    return mapFetch;
  }

  void _onDaySelected(DateTime day, List events) {
    print('CALLBACK: _onDaySelected');
    setState(() {
      _selectedEvents = events;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    final _selectedDay = DateTime.now();
    _selectedEvents = [];
    _calendarController = CalendarController();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    );

    _animationController.forward();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      getTask1().then((val) => setState(() {
            _events = val;
          }));
      //print( ' ${_events.toString()} ');
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _calendarController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildTableCalendarWithBuilders(),
            const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            Expanded(child: _buildEventList()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTableCalendarWithBuilders() {
    return TableCalendar(
      //locale: 'pl_PL',
      calendarController: _calendarController,
      events: _events,
      //holidays: _holidays,
      initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
      formatAnimation: FormatAnimation.slide,
      startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.sunday,
      availableGestures: AvailableGestures.all,
      availableCalendarFormats: const {
        CalendarFormat.month: '',
        CalendarFormat.week: '',
      },
      calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
        outsideDaysVisible: false,
        weekendStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.blue[800]),
        holidayStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.blue[800]),
      ),
      daysOfWeekStyle: DaysOfWeekStyle(
        weekendStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.blue[600]),
      ),
      headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
        centerHeaderTitle: true,
        formatButtonVisible: false,
      ),
      builders: CalendarBuilders(
        selectedDayBuilder: (context, date, _) {
          return FadeTransition(
            opacity: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_animationController),
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, left: 6.0),
              color: Colors.deepOrange[300],
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              child: Text(
                '${date.day}',
                style: TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 16.0),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        todayDayBuilder: (context, date, _) {
          return Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, left: 6.0),
            color: Colors.amber[400],
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            child: Text(
              '${date.day}',
              style: TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 16.0),
            ),
          );
        },
        markersBuilder: (context, date, events, holidays) {
          final children = <Widget>[];

          if (events.isNotEmpty) {
            children.add(
              Positioned(
                right: 1,
                bottom: 1,
                child: _buildEventsMarker(date, events),
              ),
            );
          }

          if (holidays.isNotEmpty) {
            children.add(
              Positioned(
                right: -2,
                top: -2,
                child: _buildHolidaysMarker(),
              ),
            );
          }

          return children;
        },
      ),
      onDaySelected: (date, events) {
        _onDaySelected(date, events);
        _animationController.forward(from: 0.0);
      },
      onVisibleDaysChanged: _onVisibleDaysChanged,
    );
  }

  void _onVisibleDaysChanged(
      DateTime first, DateTime last, CalendarFormat format) {
    print('CALLBACK: _onVisibleDaysChanged');
  }

  Widget _buildEventsMarker(DateTime date, List events) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        color: _calendarController.isSelected(date)
            ? Colors.brown[500]
            : _calendarController.isToday(date)
                ? Colors.brown[300]
                : Colors.blue[400],
      ),
      width: 16.0,
      height: 16.0,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          '${events.length}',
          style: TextStyle().copyWith(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 12.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildHolidaysMarker() {
    return Icon(
      Icons.add_box,
      size: 20.0,
      color: Colors.blueGrey[800],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildEventList() {
    return ListView(
      children: _selectedEvents
          .map((event) => Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(width: 0.8),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                ),
                margin:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 4.0),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(event.toString()),
                  onTap: () => print('$event tapped!'),
                ),
              ))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}

class EventModel {
  String kodeEvent;
  DateTime tanggalEvent;
  String judulEvent;
  String lokasiEvent;
  String isiEvent;
  String fotoEvent;
  String waktuEvent;
  String statusEvent;
  String createBy;
  DateTime createTime;
  String updateBy;
  String updateTime;

  EventModel({
    this.kodeEvent,
    this.tanggalEvent,
    this.judulEvent,
    this.lokasiEvent,
    this.isiEvent,
    this.fotoEvent,
    this.waktuEvent,
    this.statusEvent,
    this.createBy,
    this.createTime,
    this.updateBy,
    this.updateTime,
  });

  factory EventModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => EventModel(
        kodeEvent: json["kodeEvent"],
        tanggalEvent: DateTime.parse(json["tanggalEvent"]),
        judulEvent: json["judulEvent"],
        lokasiEvent: json["lokasiEvent"],
        isiEvent: json["isiEvent"],
        fotoEvent: json["fotoEvent"],
        waktuEvent: json["waktuEvent"],
        statusEvent: json["statusEvent"],
        createBy: json["createBy"],
        createTime: DateTime.parse(json["createTime"]),
        updateBy: json["updateBy"],
        updateTime: json["updateTime"],
      );
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer,  I already trying it and works , But it's possible if i use my model in my question instead of your model from appquicktype ? I trying to use my model to fit your answer , but i'm stuck in looping `for (int i = 0; i < event.data.length; i++) ` My model not have **data.length**

Comment: I have update my answer to fit your model. please see my updated answer.

Comment: This is what i looking for !
But i have question and i dont know it will should be create new post in SO or not. I have little change from your code to fit with my case https://gist.github.com/zgramming/fcc8d6585cecb7ece5c5c7088c7e421f  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOwyH.gif. But I'm curious , it's possible to show **Detail Of Event** On Tap event on Calendar ?  Because  if Tap and  print **event** from **_buildEventList**, it only send 1 value is **judulEvent**. It's possible if i Tap on **Event** from **_buildEventList** can send all value from API ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFeh.png

Comment: You can pass _selectedEvents , If you have trouble to pass , you can move out List _selectedEvents and it become global to all of your widget. pass with pushnamed you can reference https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.

Comment: I'm thinking about this line `mapFetch[tanggalEvent] =List.from(original)..addAll([resultEventList[i].judulEvent]);` , instead of only passing **judulEvent** , it's possible to passing all key like **code,date,location and content of event** ?

Comment: Yes. you can pass or use mapFetch[tanggalEvent]  because it's a Map<DateTime, List>, this variable contains all of your events in this app.

Comment: I already change instead of passing only **titleEvent** , I passing all key like this `mapFetch[tanggalEvent] = List.from(original)..addAll([resultEventList[i]]);`. But i get error `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<EventModel>'`. If you do not mind , i want  move this discussion to chat.

Comment: In void _onDaySelected(DateTime day, List events) , you can keep day (selected day) to a variable and pass mapFetch[day] then you get same value as _selectedEvents , I will back after one or two hour for a meeting.

Comment: I have put a full working demo in you gist. you can copy paste run it.

Comment: You saved my day !!! I will make litte change from your code
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dTmH.jpg

Comment: any of you made this work in landscape? the calendar always gets an overflow

Comment: After update of Table calendar version it's not work