# How to add events from external API to a calender in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using  table_calendar plugin(https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar#-readme-tab-) in my flutter application. I want to add the events dynamically to the calendar from external API. When the user opens the calendar all the events should be displayed. This is the code i am using.

Getting the error: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List'

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Map<DateTime, List> _events;
  List _selectedEvents;
  AnimationController _animationController;
  CalendarController _calendarController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();// calling the external API
    final _selectedDay = DateTime.now();
// Do not want to hardcode like this
    _events = {
      DateTime.parse("2020-07-03") : ['Event A6', 'Event B6'],
      DateTime.parse("2020-07-04") : ['Event A7', 'Event B6'],
      DateTime.parse("2020-07-05") : ['Event A6', 'Event B6'],
      DateTime.parse("2020-07-06") : ['Event A6', 'Event B6'],
     };

    _selectedEvents = _events[_selectedDay] ?? [];
    _calendarController = CalendarController();

    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    );

    _animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    _calendarController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onDaySelected(DateTime day, List events) {
  
        print('ggggCALLBACK: _onDaySelected');
        
                 
        setState(() {
          _selectedEvents = events;
        });
      }
    
      void _onVisibleDaysChanged(DateTime first, DateTime last, CalendarFormat format) {
        print('CALLBACK: _onVisibleDaysChanged');
      }
    
      void _onCalendarCreated(DateTime first, DateTime last, CalendarFormat format) {
        print('CALLBACK: _onCalendarCreated');
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              
              _buildTableCalendar(),
              // _buildTableCalendarWithBuilders(),
              const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
             _buildButtons(),
              const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
              Expanded(child: _buildEventList()),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      // Simple TableCalendar configuration (using Styles)
      Widget _buildTableCalendar() {
        return TableCalendar(
          calendarController: _calendarController,
          events: _events,
         // holidays: _holidays,
          startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
          calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
            selectedColor: Colors.deepOrange[400],
            todayColor: Colors.deepOrange[200],
            markersColor: Colors.brown[700],
            outsideDaysVisible: false,
          ),
          headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
            formatButtonTextStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),
            formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.deepOrange[400],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
            ),
          ),
          onDaySelected: _onDaySelected,
          onVisibleDaysChanged: _onVisibleDaysChanged,
          onCalendarCreated: _onCalendarCreated,
        );
      }
    
         
    
      Widget _buildButtons() {
        final dateTime = _events.keys.elementAt(_events.length - 2);
        debugPrint(dateTime.toString());
    
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
          
            const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Set day ${dateTime.day}-${dateTime.month}-${dateTime.year}'),
              onPressed: () {
                _calendarController.setSelectedDay(
                  DateTime(dateTime.year, dateTime.month, dateTime.day),
                  runCallback: true,
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    
      Widget _buildEventList() {
        return ListView(
          children: _selectedEvents
              .map((event) => Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(width: 0.8),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                    ),
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 4.0),
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(event.toString()),
                      onTap: () => print('$event tapped!'),
                    ),
                  ))
              .toList(),
        );
      }
```

The data from the external API is fetched using the following

```
Future getData() async {
      _events = {};
      final response = await http.get("https://MyExternal API")
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      print(response.body);
      for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        print(jsonData[i]['eventdate']);
        _events[DateTime.parse(jsonData[i]['eventdate'])] = jsonData[i]['eventdescription'];
       }
  }
```

The Json Response is : `[{"eventdate":"2020-07-02","eventdescription":"hello"}]`

I have referred the answer by @chunhunghan [Flutter Table Calendar : Showing Event from API to Table Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60276303/flutter-table-calendar-showing-event-from-api-to-table-calendar) but bit hard to understand.