# How to show my own events in flutter calendar?

Tags: flutter, events, calendar, flutter-dependencies, show

I need to show my own events ondateselect in table calendar package. Here I am using **table_calendar** package with **3.0.3** version. Please help me out
I am using new version of flutter with null safety.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';


class TableEventsExample extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const TableEventsExample({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _TableEventsExampleState createState() => _TableEventsExampleState();
}

class _TableEventsExampleState extends State<TableEventsExample> {
  DateTime? _selectedDay;
  DateTime _focusedDay = DateTime.now();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TableCalendar(
          firstDay: DateTime(2021,1,1), 
          focusedDay: DateTime.now(),
          lastDay: DateTime(2030,12,31),
          selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
            return isSameDay(_selectedDay, day);
          },
          onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedDay = selectedDay;
              _focusedDay = focusedDay;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that when you select a date you want for example print that day under the calendar? Please add more details regarding what you want to do

Comment: hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67866071/10157127) will solve the issue

Comment: On date select i want to show hoilday or like events on that day. Down